# NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRouteSnapshot

Tags: ngxs

```
constructor(private activatedSnapshot: ActivatedSnapshot, private store: Store) {}

route() {
    this.store.dispatch(new Navigate(
       ['..', 'contacts'], 
       null, 
       { relativeTo: this.activatedSnapshot }
    )); 
}
```

Is there something I'm supposed to import?

Answer (score 3):

Try injecting [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) instead of `ActivatedSnapshot`.

So the code will become:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private store: Store) {}

route() {
    this.store.dispatch(new Navigate(
       ['..', 'contacts'], 
       null, 
       { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute }
    )); 
}
```