# Use route parameters in guard service

Tags: angular, routes

I'm trying to check if a user can access a certain component based on the route.
So I need to get a route parameter in the guard service.
I read in other topics that you need the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` when you need route information before the targetted page has loaded.

Is that (still) correct? When I'm trying to use that approach I got a "No provider for ActivatedRouteSnapshot!" error, which gets me back to using ActivatedRoute according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303850/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-activatedroutesnapshot)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { EventManagerService } from './services/database/event/eventmanager.service';

@Injectable()
export class ManagerGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private eventManagerService: EventManagerService, private route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
  }

  canActivate() {
    const eventId = this.route.paramMap.get('eventId');
    return this.eventManagerService.getManagerProfile(eventId)
      .pipe(
        tap(authenticated => {
          if (!authenticated) {
            this.router.navigate(['manager']);
          }
        }),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll spot the issue here and the solution in the documentation https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I was using the route and state in the constructor, while it is already provided in the `canActivate` interface

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { EventManagerService } from './services/database/event/eventmanager.service';

@Injectable()
export class ManagerGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private eventManagerService: EventManagerService,) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
```